# Shading every other row in a VB.net Listview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, dynamic, modalpopup

I have been Googling this for about a day now, and every post I find is too old and Visual Studio doesn't recognize some pieces of code that people have posted. I have a dynamically populated Listview. I would really like every other line to be shaded for readability purposes, and just can't figure it out.

Everything I try to do messes with the Modal PopupExtender that I have inside of the Listview. It trys to shade the lines inside the PopUpBox too. This is one of the Listviews that I would like shaded.

```
<!-- Descriptions -->
<asp:TabPanel ID="tab2"  runat="server" HeaderText="Descriptions">
<HeaderTemplate>Descriptions</HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ul class="info">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvDescriptions" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsMarketingDescriptions" DataKeyNames="MarketingID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ViewDescriptionButton" runat="server"><%#Eval("MarketingTitle")%></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Panel ID="ViewDescriptionPanel" runat="server" CssClass="DescModalPopup">                   <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">View Description
                <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelDescriptionButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../images/exit.png" AlternateText="" Style="float:right;"/>
                </div>
                    <asp:Label ID="Description" runat="server" style="padding:5px;"><%# Eval("MarketingData") %></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel> 
                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ViewDescriptionModal" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="true" PopupControlID="ViewDescriptionPanel" TargetControlID="ViewDescriptionButton" CancelControlID="CancelDescriptionButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>              
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </ul>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `AlternatingItemTemplate` to specify a different background color for alternating items.

Are you trying to do something like this with the ModalPopupExtender?:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Panel pnl = e.Item.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
    if (pnl != null)
    {
        pnl.BackColor = ListView1.Items.IndexOf(e.Item) % 2 == 1 ? Color.PeachPuff : Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL.....That only works on my Listviews that don't have a modalpopupextender connected to them. I was hoping to get some help with the modal.

Comment: I edited the original post with an image of the page with the AlternatingItemTemplate

Comment: What do you mean *connected* to them? The `ModalPopupExtender` is extending a `Panel`, right? If not, it should be.

Comment: Are you trying to shade the background color of the popup?

Comment: Ok, it must've been something I was doing because when I refreshed the page it was fine. Maybe I didn't wait for it to save or something I don't know. hah